# Лучшие алгоритмы сжатия текста

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие

С каждым годом алгоритмы сжатия совершенствуются, появляется что-то новое, или модификация существующих.

**Вопрос:**

**Какие из ныне существующих, на 2016 год, алгоритмов сжатия текстовой информации дают лучший результат (естественно, без потерь)?**

Дополнительно:

- текст будет представлять себя наборы символов латиницы, кириллицы, знаков препинания - из ASCII (cp866 или win-1251), возможно еще псевдографика будет
- те же наборы символов, но представленные в кодировке ru_RU.UTF-8

Пока на слуху, но это уже относительно давно, алгоритм PPMd, PPMz. Есть что-то более совершенное?

Comment: Нет, набор текстов неизвестен. Известен "более-менее" набор символов, который используется в тексте. В принципе, можно на первых этапах вычислить частотную таблицу символов - но это будет только "отправной точкой", и, имхо, не даст ощутимого выхлопа по сравнению с существующими алгоритмами.Нужно что-то кардинально новое.

Comment: Без словаря у вас не будет "лучшего" результата, это однозначно, так что лучше ищите способы его составить.

Comment: Допустим, у меня есть словарь, но как его сохранить? Перекладывать весь контент в словарь - можно, но встает вопрос о том как сжимать уже его.

Comment: Посмотрите семейство паковщиков Paq8: http://dhost.info/paq8/

Comment: @bukkojot , пару лет назад смотрел архиватор zpaq - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPAQ. Скорее всего paq* оттуда. Да, жмет он неплохо. Но того отрыва, который давал на текстах архиватор HA (на основе PPM) по сравнению с компрессорами общего назначения - пока не вижу.

Comment: Оставлю пока, чтобы было - http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html

Comment: ZPAQ лишь одна из веток, ссылка на семейство оных тут не просто так - там куча версий, затюненных под разные частные случаи. Иногда бывают очень интересные. Часть я простестить не смог, так как хотят ну очень много памяти и времени.

Comment: В 2к17 можно вообще не сжимать

Comment: а цель сжатия? если, к примеру, один раз сжимаем, потом много шлем - это одно, а если постоянно сжимать/разжимать - это другое.

Comment: zpaq - это ускоренный paq, который за раз моделирует несколько битов вместо одного, что ухудшает сжатие. paq8 - это наоборот последняя версия полного paq. paq8px - одна из её веток (благо что программа опен-сорсная, веток было десятки), вроде на данный момент наиболее живая.

Comment: цель сжатия - архивация неизменяемой по времени текстовой информации. Типа "один раз мучительно сжимаем" - потом пользуемся путем разархивации налету.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Лучший ответ на этот вопрос - спросите на [форуме encode.ru](https://encode.ru/forums/2-Data-Compression). Я лично не слежу за этим совсем уж пристально, поэтому навскидку: paq8px, emma, cmix (у каждого есть своя ветка на форуме). Кроме этого, препроцессинг - словарная замена (xml-wrt), трюки Grabowski. Имейте в виду, что тексты должны быть достаточно велики (ну хотя бы сотни килобайт) и скорость сжатия/распаковки может быть в районе нескольких кб/с, а многопоточность невозможна без ухудшения сжатия.

Собственно приведённая вами же ссылка http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html даёт достаточно исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос. Все алгоритмы такого уровня получают ветки на форуме encode.ru и тестируются Маттом на тексте английской википедии.

Да, язык/кодировка (при условии что она 8-битная) имеют значение только для словарных препроцессоров - они обычно работают только с латиницей. Остальные алгоритмы хорошо работают с любыми языками.

Если же вам на самом деле нужно не максимальное сжатие, а оптимальное сочетание скорости и степени сжатия, то для текстов я предпочитаю [bsc](http://libbsc.com/), тем более что это единственная библиотека сжатия общего назначения, способная использовать GPU.

Comment: @Bulat , приведенная мною ссылка не говорит о том, что есть что-то кардинально лучшее. "Говорит" - есть "много хорошего". Нужно не оптимальное, а максимальное сжатие (при условии вменяемого времени распаковки), скорость же сжатия вообще не влияет.

Comment: А я и не говорю про кардинально лучшее, тем более что и не знаю ваших критериев оного. Говорю, что вы можете найти там все современные алгоритмы и сами подобрать то что удовлетворяет вашим требованиям - там есть и скорость упаковки/распаковки, и наличие сорцов.

Comment: Далее, пишите конкретно какая скорость вам нужна. Лучшие алгоритмы сжатия симметричны и однопоточны, но чуть ниже есть и ассиметричные. Навскидку из этой таблицы достаточно быстрые и опен-сорсные - mcm, bcm, bsc, glza (это где-то от нескольких мегабайт до нескольких десятков мегабайт скорость распаковки).

Comment: @Majestio, не знаю нужно ли упоминать ваш ник, чтобы вы как автор топика получили уведомление о новом комментарии

Comment: @Bulat , я получаю пометки об ответах в комментариях, но когда общаюсь - стараюсь обращаться по никам, чтобы не было путаницы в ответах. Ну а по вопросу ... да, есть куча "близких" алгоритмов. Разница в степени сжатия в 1-2-3% для меня несущественна (возьму 1% с максимальной скоростью сжатия). А вот если бы был алгоритм со степенью сжатия, к примеру, на 20% еще меньше - на счет скорости сжатия даже бы не задумался, выбрал бы его. Но пока увы.

Comment: К сожалению, лучшие алгоритмы симметричны. Ассиметричные же начинаются со скорости распаковки в десятки мегабайт/сек.

Answer (score 8):

Попробовал сжимать "Войну и Мир" ([отсюда](http://vojnaimir.ru/files/book1.txt))

```
$ 7za a -mm=deflate -mx9 -- war_and_peace.txt.deflate.7z 
$ 7za a -mm=bzip2 -mx9 -- war_and_peace.txt.bz2.7z war_and_peace.txt
$ 7za a -mm=lzma2 -mx9 -- war_and_peace.txt.lzma2.7z war_and_peace.txt
$ 7za a -mm=ppmd -mx9 -- war_and_peace.txt.ppmd.7z war_and_peace.txt
$ dir
1 473 547 war_and_peace.txt
  577 577 war_and_peace.txt.deflate.7z
  481 030 war_and_peace.txt.lzma2.7z
  445 240 war_and_peace.txt.bz2.7z
  391 270 war_and_peace.txt.ppmd.7z
```

Видно, что PPMd самый эффективный на "Войне и Мире".
За ним идет BZ2, потом LZMA2 и Deflate.

---

Попробовал cmix. Он действительно жрет 36 Гб памяти и сжимал 43 минуты.

```
$ cmix -c war_and_peace.txt war_and_peace.txt.cmix
1473547 bytes -> 348461 bytes in 2633.81 s.
cross entropy: 1.892
```

У него еще есть режим со словарем (орфоргафическим), но в комплекте идет только словарь из ~45 тыс. английских слов.

---

Впрочем это довольно старые и широко известные алгоримы. Возможно существует что-то другое, более подходящее для текстов которые надо сживать автору вопроса.

---

Мне нечего было делать, и я разбил "Войну и Мир" по словам и закодировал их Хаффманом. Получилось 444Кб не считая таблицу. Т.е. это была плохая идея.

```
>>> text = open(r'c:\_tmp\war_and_peace.txt', 'rb').read().decode('cp1251')
>>> import re
>>> words = re.findall(r'(\w+|.)', text)
>>> len(text), len(words)
(1473547, 534395)
>>> def huffman_table(symbols):
    import collections
    freq = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for s in symbols: freq[s] += 1
    roots = [(f,[(s,'')]) for s,f in freq.items()]
    while True:
        roots.sort()
        (f0,t0),(f1,t1),tail=roots[0],roots[1],roots[2:]
        table=[(s,'0'+c) for s,c in t0]+[(s,'1'+c) for s,c in t1]
        if len(tail) == 0:
            return dict(table)
        roots = tail+[(f0+f1,table)]


>>> table = huffman_table(words)
>>> len(table)
35421
>>> def huffman_encode(symbols, table):
    buffer = ''
    out = bytearray()
    for s in symbols:
        buffer += table[s]
        while len(buffer) >= 8:
            b, buffer = buffer[:8], buffer[8:]
            out.append(int(b, 2))
    size = len(out)*8+len(buffer)
    if len(buffer) != 0:
        out.append(int(buffer, 2))
    return out, size

>>> encoded, size_bits = huffman_encode(words, table)
>>> size_bits/8
454533.75
```

Comment: А если для начала забыть в "Войне и мире" про все знаки препинания и оставить только целиком слова, состоящие из строчных русских букв и разделенные пробелом, потом сделать стемминг, записать что-то вроде полнотекстового индекса (реверсной таблицы) из записей вида: основа/форма/позиция/форма/позиция/форма/позиция/форма/позиция в тексте, и попробовать сжать его хоть gzip? Эксперимент типа.

Comment: разве идея не интересная? В файле полнотекстового индекса будет куча повторяющихся через небольшой интервал одинаковых фрагментов. Такие вещи LZ77 очень хорошо пакует.

Comment: @Abyx , спасибо за ответ. Но, увы, не то. Используемые алгоритмы по результатом близки друг к другу. Т.е. "отрыва" не наблюдается, наблюдается близкая конкуренция. К тестам Войны и Мира можно еще добавить `zpaq64 a war_and_peace.zpaq war_and_peace.txt -method 5` с результатом `381520 байт`. Под "отрывом" я понимаю более значительное сжатие. Как пример, для графики - появление DjVu при повсеместно существующем TIFF.

Comment: И еще ... Хотел попробовать `cmix` (http://www.byronknoll.com/cmix.html) - но комп не потянул по требованиям памяти. Там около 32Gb оперативы нужно 0_o. Хотя, желаемого "отрыва", согласно проведенным сравнениям другими, не следует ожидать.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov - пытаться самому придумать конкурентоспособный алгоритм сжатия в комментариях на SO - это примерно как записать доказательство теоремы Ферма на полях книги. шансов на успех очень мало ;)

Comment: насчёт cmix - в http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html есть столбцы скорости упаковки/распаковки. 600 тыщ наносекунд/байт означает скорость в 1.5 КБ/с. уже на этом этапе всё становится ясно :D

Answer (score 0):

Восьмибитное представление фтопку, зачастую это можно уменьшить .(имею в виду  конечно восьмибитное представление символов). Если текст двуязычный пред-обработка: чтобы уменьшить алфавит - использовать соответствия  символов t=т g=г L=Л и т.д.  и в тексте маркер с указанием на начало-окончание текста на латинице. Ещё другой подход: использовать как единицу кодирования текста не символы, а слоги (чтобы СЛАГАТЬ поэмы и тексты); если правильно помню 30% слогов составляют 70-75% текста. Ещё , друзья, напоминание немного в офтоп - есть методы сжатия "с потерями" которые при восстановлении дают высокую точность! И, напоследок: для максимального сжатия текстов следует использовать алгоритмы которые соответствуют спецификации файла (спецификации отрывка текста) по категориям- художеств. литература, или технич. лит-ра, или тексты одного автора, или произведение в котором используется несколько языков и др. Желаю успехов!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).